# Count subobjects in json

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I have a json object that could look like this that i need to loop through. The problem is when i do this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= jsonResult.count-1; i++) {
}
```

It only returns 1 since there is only 1 object in match, but there is a lot of subobjects that i would like to count i've tried doing something like this

```
[jsonResult valueForKey:@"match"].count
```

But that is not possible.

How can i count all the matches (the subobjects)?

The json code:

```
match =     (
            {
        awayteam = Elche;
        hometeam = Espanol;
        location = "Estadi Cornell\U00e0-El Prat";
        playdate = "2014-03-09";
        time = "04:00:00";
    },
            {
        awayteam = Betis;
        hometeam = Elche;
        location = "Mart\U00ednez Valero";
        playdate = "2014-03-16";
        time = "04:00:00";
    };

}
```

Comment: Use a simple recursive walk of the tree.

Comment: (And that's not valid JSON.  Or a valid NSDictionary dump.)

Comment: What is the type of `match`. I can see its not a valid NSDictionary/NSArray either. it starts with "(" and ends with "}". There is no such object in objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top level `NSDictionary` object contains an `NSArray` of sub `NSDictionary`'s. So you should be able to do something like:

```
int subObjects = ((NSArray *)jsonResult[@"match"]).count;
// subObjects is count of all sub objects
```